# Undo safely remove device

Tags: usb

After I have asked the OS to safely remove device (USB) and can no longer access it. Without plugging out and in the USB how can I make the OS gain access to the USB device again?

Basically triggering the same event which is fired when the OS detects a device was plugged in, or something else.

Answer (score 1):

You can do so by following below steps:

> a. cd /sys/bus/usb/drivers/usb-storage
>
> b. Find out to which usb bus, your storage device is connected. e.g. If it is connected to bus "2-1.2:1.0"
>
> c. Execute the command `echo -n "2-1.2:1.0" > bind`
>   It will do the same thing as plug-out and plug-in do
>
> d. You can also umount the storage device by executing:
>   `echo -n "2-1.2:1.0" > unbind`

Replace the bus ID by appropriate bus id

Answer (score 1):

There may be easier ways depending on your DE, etc, but here's a basic strategy that will work everywhere:

**I. Figure out the device node.**

These are in the `/dev/` directory, and pretty easy to find once you get the idea.  A big clue is that USB storage devices usually have at least one partition.  This means there will be at least *two* nodes, one for the device as a whole and one for each partition.  The naming scheme gives this away, because if the device is `sda`, the first partition will be `sda1`.  If you look at `ls /dev`, you'll notice there aren't that many things following that pattern.  Ignore all the `tty` and `vcs` things.

Also, the name *may* follow the same pattern as your hard drive(s), using `a`, `b`, `c` etc. in order.  For example, if you have two hard drives and one is `sda` and the other is `sdb`, a USB device added subsequently might be `sdc`.  These then each have partitions (`sda1`, `sda2`, `sdb1`, `sdc1`, etc).

Note that it is possible to format a device such that it doesn't have any partitions, in which case the device and the filesystem on it are accessed by the same node with no number (e.g. `sdc`).  You probably haven't done that, but just in case, keep in mind it is possible.

The most sure fire way to figure this out the first time is to go `ls /dev > one.txt` while the device is still plugged in but unmounted.  Now pull it out, wait a few seconds, and `ls /dev > two.txt`.  Then: `diff one.txt two.txt`.  Whatever comes out is the name of your device node.  It will probably be the same next time, unless you have a lot of devices you are often adding and removing, in which case the `a`, `b`, `c` suffix may be different.

You can enforce specific device node names for specific devices using `udev`, but if it's just for this, it isn't really worth bothering with.  It is handy if you want things mounted specific ways at boot.

**II. Mount the device/partition.**

You need superuser privileges:

```
sudo mount /dev/sdc1 /mnt/usb
```

That's the partition node first, then the mount point.  See `man mount`.

Comment: Remounting is only half the battle. First, you need to reconnect the USB device.

Comment: @Gilles :  I haven't seen one become disconnected as per the dupe you linked, too bad there was no real explanation for that.  I guess it's up to the OP to clarify what was meant here.